# How does Squirt's Necklace work?

Tags: diablo-iii

The new squirts necklace has an effect that boosts your damage 'while not taking damage'.

I've noticed that sometimes the effect stays even though I am taking damage, and other times, while I'm taking no damage (such as under the effect of a shield pylon), it still gets removed.

What exactly counts as taking damage or not?

[image]

Comment: here's an image of my squirts effect being lost and regained while under the effects of a shield pylon in case anyone's curious: https://i.imgur.com/1aSPuCv.png

Comment: seems like it's bugged but I'll do more research

Comment: Could you list your gear and skills/passives?  I can see you are using focus and restraint as well as the unhallowed essence set, neither of which I think affect your HP, but perhaps there is another skill/item you are wearing that could be changing your life.  (Can't think of anything off the top of my head, but just speculating).

Comment: Did a quick test on my necromancer.  Skills that cost life didn't seem to remove the effect, neither is standing in the blood springs or the fire ground in halls of agony (although they did almost kill me!!!).  I also found some shield pylons in a rift and stood in a few different elite affixes and nothing removed the effect.  Does sound like a bug, but may hard to say without exactly knowing what was going on when it happened to you.

Comment: @PawnInGameOfLife just standard UE gear, no awareness passive or anything that would cause life loss.

Comment: I really do hope that by 'taking damage' they meant losing HP and not getting hit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking damagein case of the *Squirt's Necklace* is an event, where you 
**lose HitPoints due to an attack, skill or effect of an enemy as well as after death effects**.

You can therefore count in **ground effects and damage through map objects**. You see you most likely take damage rather frequently and need 10 seconds to reach the full buff effect again (aka 10 stacks).

The only exception to taking HitPoint damage is **self-inflicted damage** like f.e. necromancer skills that cost life.

Losing this effect under the effect of a **shielding pylon** is a known bug, sadly, and still not yet fixed.

Keep in mind, that you don't lose the buff while taking damage, but rather when you lose any HitPoints. Because of this it is f.e. on wizard a strategy to focus on **shielding** your life pool, since **absorbed damage** does not count towards taking HitPoint damage.

Damage instances that you **dodge** also don't remove the effect of squirt's.

Hope this somewhat clears things up for you. Good loot and useful primals!

Comment: Welcome here, don't hesitate to take [the tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need.  As asked in the bounty, you could improve your answer by citing sources. It is, however a pretty good and complete answer, not only addressing the bug part, but also answering the actual question "How does squirts necklace work?".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, like @Zoma suggested, some additional links to support it would been nice.

Answer (score 3):

From personal testing I have found that the frozen affix from elites will cause the buff to vanish.  Looking at the diablo bug page [here](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/d3/t/squirts-necklace-still-being-bugged/2570) shows that some other things will cause it to vanish as well (they mention possibly poisonous clouds from when accursed die and the trails anarchs leave when they charge).  I only personally tested the frozen however.